# one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation:

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to computer a loss of policy target network in Deep Deterministic Policy Gradient Algorithms with pytorch 1.5, and I get the following error.

```
File "F:\agents\ddpg.py", line 128, in train_model
    policy_loss.backward()
  File "E:\conda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 198, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "E:\conda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 100, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [128, 1]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead
. Hint: enable anomaly detection to find the operation that failed to compute its gradient, with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).
```

There are my networks and training progress. In the actor network, the lenght of output vector is 20 which means a continuous action. The input of critic net consists of state vector and action vector.

```py
"""
ddpg actor
"""
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 input_size,
                 output_size,
                 output_limit=1.0,
                 hidden_sizes=(64, 64),
                 activation=torch.relu,
                 output_activation=identity,
                 use_output_layer=True,
                 use_actor=False,
                 ):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()

        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.output_limit = output_limit
        self.hidden_sizes = hidden_sizes
        self.activation = activation
        self.output_activation = output_activation
        self.use_output_layer = use_output_layer
        self.use_actor = use_actor

        # Set hidden layers
        self.hidden_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        in_size = self.input_size
        for next_size in self.hidden_sizes:
            fc = nn.Linear(in_size, next_size)
            in_size = next_size
            self.hidden_layers.append(fc)

        # Set output layers
        if self.use_output_layer:
            self.output_layer1 = nn.Linear(in_size, self.output_size // 2)
            self.output_layer2 = nn.Linear(in_size, self.output_size // 2)
        else:
            self.output_layer = identity

    def forward(self, x):

        for hidden_layer in self.hidden_layers:
            x = self.activation(hidden_layer(x))
        x1 = torch.sigmoid(self.output_layer1(x))
        x2 = F.softmax(self.output_layer2(x), dim=0)
        out = torch.cat((x1, x2), dim=-1)


        # If the network is used as actor network, make sure output is in correct range
        out = out * self.output_limit if self.use_actor else out
        return out



"""
DDPG critic, TD3 critic, SAC qf, TAC qf
"""

class critic(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 input_size,
                 output_size,
                 output_limit=1.0,
                 hidden_sizes=(64, 64),
                 activation=torch.relu,
                 output_activation=identity,
                 use_output_layer=True,
                 use_actor=False,
                 ):
        super().__init__()

        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.output_limit = output_limit
        self.hidden_sizes = hidden_sizes
        self.activation = activation
        self.output_activation = output_activation
        self.use_output_layer = use_output_layer
        self.use_actor = use_actor

        # Set hidden layers
        self.hidden_layers = nn.ModuleList()
        in_size = self.input_size
        for next_size in self.hidden_sizes:
            fc = nn.Linear(in_size, next_size)
            in_size = next_size
            self.hidden_layers.append(fc)

        # Set output layers
        if self.use_output_layer:
            self.output_layer = nn.Linear(in_size, self.output_size)
        else:
            self.output_layer = identity

    def forward(self, x, a):
        q= torch.cat([x, a], dim=1)

        for hidden_layer in self.hidden_layers:
            q = self.activation(hidden_layer(q))
        q = torch.tanh(self.output_layer(q))

        return q
```

```
    def train_model(self):
        batch = self.replay_buffer.sample(self.batch_size)
        obs1 = batch['obs1']
        obs2 = batch['obs2']
        acts = batch['acts']
        rews = batch['rews']
        done = batch['done']
        # Check shape of experiences

        # Prediction Q(s,(s)), Q(s,a), Q‾(s',‾(s'))
        with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True):
            print("obs1",obs1.shape) #(64,22)
            print("a1",self.policy(obs1).shape) #(64,20)
            q_pi = self.qf(obs1, self.policy(obs1))
            q = self.qf(obs1, acts).squeeze(1)
            q_pi_target = self.qf_target(obs2, self.policy_target(obs2)).squeeze(1)

            # Target for Q regression
            q_backup = rews + self.gamma * (1 - done) * q_pi_target
            q_backup.to(self.device)

            # DDPG losses
            policy_loss = -q_pi.mean()
            qf_loss = F.mse_loss(q, q_backup.detach())

            # Update Q-function network parameter

            self.qf_optimizer.zero_grad()
            qf_loss.backward()
            nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.qf.parameters(), self.gradient_clip_qf)
            self.qf_optimizer.step()

            # Update policy network parameter
            self.policy_optimizer.zero_grad()
            # here is the error
            policy_loss.backward()
            nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(self.policy.parameters(), self.gradient_clip_policy)
            self.policy_optimizer.step()

            # Polyak averaging for target parameter
            soft_target_update(self.policy, self.policy_target)
            soft_target_update(self.qf, self.qf_target)

            # Save losses
            self.policy_losses.append(policy_loss.item())
            self.qf_losses.append(qf_loss.item())
```

I also take the advice given by the hint which uses  `with torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True).`
The result is

```
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    agent.run(100)
  File "F:\agents\ddpg.py", line 184, in run
    self.train_model()
  File "F:\agents\ddpg.py", line 109, in train_model
    q_pi = self.qf(obs1, self.policy(obs1))
  File "E:\conda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "F:\agents\common\networks.py", line 115, in forward
    q = torch.tanh(self.output_layer(q))
  File "E:\conda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 550, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "E:\conda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 87, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "E:\conda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1610, in linear
    ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
 (print_stack at ..\torch\csrc\autograd\python_anomaly_mode.cpp:60)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    agent.run(100)
  File "F:/agents\ddpg.py", line 184, in run
    self.train_model()
  File "F:/agents\ddpg.py", line 130, in train_model
    policy_loss.backward()
  File "E:\conda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py", line 198, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(self, gradient, retain_graph, create_graph)
  File "E:\conda\envs\pytorch\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\__init__.py", line 100, in backward
    allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [128, 1]], which is output 0 of TBackward, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead
. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!
```

I can't find what causes failure to compute its gradient in my code.

Answer (score -1):

Just try to avoid that particular inplace operation and transform it as non inplace.

I saw cases (it has been confirmed) that PyTorch reverse mode AD struggles when creating the computational graph for specific inplace operation.

This is the current limitation.